# Powershell: Start-Process with an argument

Tags: powershell, arguments, start-process

I want to start a setup.exe with one install parameter => /download example.xml

When I tpye in  "C:\Temp\folder\setup.exe /download example.xml" in Windows Explorer Address Bar the setup.exe starts correctly.

How do I do that with Powershell?

I've tried the following:

```
$setup="C:\Temp\folder\setup.exe "
$Argument = "/download example.xml"

Start-Process $setup -ArgumentList $Argument
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it wants a list of arguments.  This might do the job

```
$setup="C:\Temp\folder\setup.exe "
$ArgumentLst = @("/download example.xml")

Start-Process $setup -ArgumentList $ArgumentLst
```